# How to add a few points to an external esri map using iframe and javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

There is an external map on : https://gis.apcrda.org/lps/index.html

i have iframed it using this code in my html page :-

```
      <iframe
        id="crdamap"
        width="500"
        height="400"
        frameborder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        marginheight="0"
        marginwidth="0"
        onLoad="load_plots_for_sale();"
        title="Avenue Plots for Sale" src="https://gis.apcrda.org/lps/index.html">
      </iframe>
```

the function to be executed on load of iframe should go like this:

```
function load_plots_for_sale(){
    $(map).on("load", function(){
       console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxzzzzzzzzzzz');
    });
}
```

but i am not able to pick the map, is there any other event which i should listen to? like:

```
layer.loadend
```

if so how can i load another layer to the map after all original layers have finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on the same domain? I think what you want to do is [only available on the same domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied). Remove your `onLoad` call in your iframe tag, then try this JS:

```
// OPEN UP CONSOLE AND SEE THE LOGS:
$("#crdamap").on('load', function() {
  var iframe= $('#crdamap')[0];
  var iframewindow= iframe.contentWindow? iframe.contentWindow : iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
  console.log('iframe window object', iframewindow);
  console.log('iframe map object', iframewindow._widgetManager.map);
});
```

[Link to demo](https://jsbin.com/favujujige/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply i will check it and reply.

Comment: @SandeepKumar did this help your issue?

Comment: No Sir it did not